# AzureDevops fails to build XUnit test with build error: The call is ambiguous between the following methods

Tags: azure-devops, xunit

The ambiguous call happens between  Assert.Throws(Action)' and 'Assert.Throws(Func) anytime we pass a local function that throws an exception to Assert.Throws.

The error does not occur locally, but does when we run the build pipe line.

Able to repo with:

```
void iut() => throw new NotImplementedException();
Assert<NotImplentedException>(iut);
```

And the following yaml for a pipeline:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/*.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    projects: '**/*.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet test'
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/*.Tests.csproj'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
```

Comment: Currently we have two easy workarounds: 1) Don't use local functions[LAME] 2) Cast each local function as an Action [Lamer]